# PCL RANSAC doesn't find solution for LINE model

Tags: c++, line, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, ransac

I'm trying to fit a line model from a pointcloud. I'm using pcl 1.9.1. And I'm facing this error :

[pcl::RandomSampleConsensus::computeModel] No samples could be selected
[pcl::SACSegmentation::segment] Error segmenting the model! No solution found.

The pointclouds I want to use are like this one :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qLrVjplmqT_SdFUXaZCYAkWHtYVEoTKR/view?usp=sharing

The code I'm using is almost the exact same as the tutorial's one (https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/planar_segmentation.html#planar-segmentation):

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
// Create the segmentation object
pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
// Optional
seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
// Mandatory
seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_LINE);
seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.1);

seg.setInputCloud (m_Lcloud);
seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
```

The only difference is the fact I want to use a line model instead of a plane one. I don't know what is happening because I saw several people doing the same and not facing this problem. I didn't see the error in this context on any topic.

My pointcloud is not so big (like 300 points) but I don't think that's the problem. I already tried to make it bigger (just added symmetrics or things like this) but same error.

The threshold is also not the problem (I think). I tried a lot of these and normally with 0.1 it should be good.

Maybe it's my version of PCL that have a problem. If someone with a latest version could try, I would appreciate.

---

I'm posting here because the pcl forum doesn't seem to be still active. So sorry if this shouldn't be here.

Thanks to anyone who takes some time for helping me !

Comment: please make the link to your point cloud public